# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors CANNOT FIGURE ISSUE

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to fix and build an Android app that is pretty old. Was making some headway but can't get past this point. I have googled like crazy and cannot figure it out.

Finally broke down and posted here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am getting Manifest merger failed with multiple errors when i build

Thank you so much for any advice!!!!

```
Here is my app.gradle:

  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  repositories {
      jcenter()
      maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven' }
  }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.inspironlogistics.wensalerts"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    //compile group: 'cz.msebera.android', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
    //compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'



    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5'
    //compile (group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpmime' , version: '4.3.5') {
        //    exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'
    //}
    //compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.afollestad:easyvideoplayer:0.3.0'

    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

AND Here is my manifest.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.inspironlogistics.wensalerts.wensalerts">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.inspironlogistics.wensalerts.wensalerts.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.inspironlogistics.wensalerts.wensalerts.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities$CreateAccountActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities$SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities$VerificationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_verification"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities$RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities$UserAccountActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_account"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <!-- GCM Receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.inspironlogistics.wensalerts.wensalerts" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- GCM Receiver Service -->
        <service
            android:name=".Utilities.GCMPushReceiverService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!-- GCM Registration Intent Service -->
        <service
            android:name=".Utilities.GCMRegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities$MessagesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_messages"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities$ImageListingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_image_listing"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities$VideoListingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_video_listing"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities$VideoPlayerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_video_player"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Looks like problem with support library version mismatch, try [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can quickly migrate an existing project to use AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar. Make sure to enable jetifier flag as shown in link.

Comment: on Android studio just go to Refactor->Migrate to AndroidX

Comment: I did try that but I still had the same issues....

Answer (score 0):

AndroidX is incompatible with support libraries so when you use the support libraries, make sure you don't import any other dependency which uses AndroidX. Doing that will always result in manifestMerger errors. It is advisable to move to the AndroidX namespace so that your app can have access to modern versions of plugins and dependencies. You can migrate automatically by Choosing Migrate to AndroidX from the Refactor menu.

- Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX on Android Studio 3.x